# Maven - Copy specific dependency with its transitive dependencies to a give location

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a maven project which I have say spring framework libraries as dependencies, I want to copy spring framework dependencies with there transitive dependencies to a location specified.

I have gone through maven dependency plugin guides at apache, I have several options where non of them will solve the complete problem.

1. copy dependencies option

> ```
> <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.8</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>copy-dependencies</id>
>             <phase>package</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
>               <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
>               <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
>               <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
>             </configuration>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
> ```

This will copy all the dependencies and there transitives to a given location, I want only spring dependencies and there transitives.

1. copying specific artifacts

> ```
> <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.8</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>copy</id>
>             <phase>package</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>copy</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>               <artifactItems>
>                 <artifactItem>
>                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>                    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
>                   <type>jar</type>
>                   <overWrite>false</overWrite>                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
>                   <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
>                 </artifactItem>
>               </artifactItems>
>               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
>               <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
>               <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
>             </configuration>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
> ```

This is not coping the transitive dependencies.

Any solution which solve my both problems.

Comment: It might be better to use [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal instead of copy goal.

Answer (score 11):

This is possible with the assembly plugin.

Plugin configuration:

```
     <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>plugins</finalName> <!--folder name in target directory-->
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>some-id</id> <!-- must match assembly id in assembly.xml-->
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> <!-- pic -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

    <id>some-id</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    org.springframework:spring-web
                </include>
            </includes>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

The important bits are `<useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>` and `<useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>`, which cause the `include` to be applied to project dependencies, but not to transitive dependencies, resulting in **spring-web artifact and it's dependencies** to be copied to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven assembly plugin for this.

Check it out and specifically the dependency set:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet

You can provide an output directory and you can specify which dependencies to put in there

There is also an option: `useTransitiveDependencies`. Set this to true to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: -1 because the `maven-assembly-plugin` with respect to this behaves exactly the same. When including only the `org.springframework:spring-web` artifact in a `dependencySet` like op suggested, only it will be copied, regardless of setting `useTransitiveDependencies`, because all its transitive dependencies are not included in the whitelist. This is seriously annoying.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I think the only approach that would work would be create a sub project or another module that depends on just the items you want and then have it generate a zip containing its deps + transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

- create module (producer) to collect dependencies and publish them as a zip.
- in consumer user depencency:unpack to unpack that zip

It is cumbersome and the exclusions still need some cherry picking, but much less and it could be run in parallel threads.

**Producer**

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>packaging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbcdrivers</artifactId>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
  <name>jdbcdrivers</name>
  <dependencies>
<!-- set up deps for capture and limit their impact on anything which depends upon this module via  optional-false -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>      
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>dist profile: hive jdbc driver ${baseName}</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib/addons/jdbcdriver/</outputDirectory>
          <useBaseVersion>true</useBaseVersion>
          <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          <includeScope>test</includeScope>
          <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
          <excludeGroupIds>org.codehaus.groovy,org.apache.ivy,jdk.tools</excludeGroupIds>  <!-- you might need to cherry pick excludes if scope doesn't worjk -->
          <prependGroupId>true</prependGroupId>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is that supposed to work out of the box? I'm getting `Unknown packaging: zip`

Comment: I sure thought so.  It is possible in the 2 years since I tried this maven did away with zip.  Zip doesn't preserve permissions so it is less good than tar (which doesn't necessarily preserve permissions either when java is involved)

Answer (score 0):

The maven dependency plugin includes an option called `includeGroupIds` in the `copy-dependencies` goal since version 2.0. Using that option (and the other include-options), you can copy only the artifacts you want to copy and include transitive dependencies:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        <includeGroupIds>org.springframework</includeGroupIds>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```