# Extract dependencies of a specific artifact with maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am using the unpack goal from maven-dependency-plugin to extract all class-files from a specified artifact to my current project.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-my-lib</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
              <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>                  
              <type>jar</type>
              <overWrite>false</overWrite>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But i am missing the dependencies of the specified artifact, i need to extract them too into my build path. I have tried other goals to get the dependencies but they do not accept to specify an artifactItem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379613/maven-copy-specific-dependency-with-its-transitive-dependencies-to-a-give-loca <- this copies but unpack is the same. Put simply, this is not an easy task. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Tunaki Currently i have packaged all ejb´s and entities in a jar due to a company specification. But doing this that way has some drawbacks like not working weaving in EclipseLink.

Comment: If you are using ejb's why not put them into a war file? Or EAR File that makes life easier...And if you really need to packag them into a single jar you should use maven-shade-plugin to do so...And why are you unpacking a jar which you are using in an other project? Why not using a simple dependency ?