# Download specific jars with dependency using maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to download a set of specific jars with there dependency and place it in a separate folder.
Below is my code from pom.xml

```
<profile>
  <id>copy-dep</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
              <version>xxx</version>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
              <version>xxx</version>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

When I use the below command only the specific dependencies get downloaded not it's transitive dependencies. Also with artifactItem if I am not able to use exclude tag.

```
mvn dependency:copy -Pcopy-dep
```

If I use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` it looks for the all the dependencies in pom.xml, which I don't want.
I tried replacing `<artifactItems>` with `<dependencies>` but also didn't work, getting below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Either artifact or artifactItems is required
```

Is there a way I can get all the selected dependencies(with transitive dependencies) and also excluding some dependencies?
If there is any better plugin available please suggest.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379613/maven-copy-specific-dependency-with-its-transitive-dependencies-to-a-give-loca